# Php add one week to a date onclick

Tags: php, ajax, date, onclick

I am printing this week number in a  element like this.

```
<span id="week"><?PHP echo date("W"); ?></span>
```

Then i have a function that collect the content of my span and adding a parameter of how many weeks i want to add to todays week.

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_week(1)">Next week</a>
```

The javascript function show_week() looks like this

```
function show_week(x){
   var d =document.getElementById("week").innerHTML;
   //alert(d.innerHTML);
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","show_week.php?w="+x+'&d='+d,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In this function i save the content from my  into a variable d witch in this case is this week number (40)

I then pass this variable with show_week.php like this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","show_week.php?w="+x+'&d='+d,true);
```

and print out the new weeknumber to the span with the id="week".

I cant get this to work properly.

HOW do i add one week to the weekdate in the span id="week"?

Comment: Whats your week date look like? What does `var_dump($_GET['w']);` output?

Comment: $_GET['w'] output how many weeks ahead i want. 1 for one week ahead and 2 for two and so on. $_GET['d'] output the content of span id="week"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your php script is passing back a good date and correctly formatted, you have not read the reply from your GET request so try this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("week").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: I get the proper date back. And everything works if i format the date like 2013-10-04 and add one day, month or year. But i want to add plus1 week or minus1 week. And this is were i have the a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1435012 This would probably answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988428/php-return-current-date-plus-7-days

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out a bit. But next time i klick on next week and collect the week number. The server dont understand that 41 is a weeknumber. So after 52 it show 53 and 54 and so on instead of begin on the first week of next year...