# Adding a Date to a function's echo in php

Tags: php, date, woocommerce, echo, strtotime

I have the following code and been trying to figure out how to add a date range within the echo, but I'm stumped. The code is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_display_badge_if_checkbox', 6 );

function bbloomer_display_badge_if_checkbox() {
    global $product;     
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_badge', true ) ) {
        echo '
<div class="woocommerce-message">Get it by </div>

';
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is insert a date 5-10 days after the current date in the format of Month(abbr),day after the "Get it by" text. So,as example, the echo would return something like: "**Get it by Feb. 1st - Feb. 5th**.

Would the line be similar to:

```
$date = strtotime("+5 day - +10 day");
echo date('M d,', $date);
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988428/return-current-date-plus-7-days)? And how would I add this to the function echo in the code above?

Comment: You cannot do  on *one* timestamt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create both date values separately e.g.

```
echo '<div class="woocommerce-message">Get it by ' . 
     date('M. dS', strtotime('+5 days')) . ' - ' .
     date('M. dS', strtotime('+10 days')) . 
     '</div>';
```

Output:

```
<div class="woocommerce-message">Get it by Mar. 26th - Mar. 31st</div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5DhKp)

Comment: how would this be customized with css?

Comment: @Matt that should be a new question as it's not really related to anything in this one. But you could also add a new class to the div and style that using css if you didn't want to style all the `woocommerce-message` divs the same way.